# Como obtener los nombres de las columnas de una tabla en SQLite

Tags: c#

estoy intentando leer los nombres de las columnas de una tabla creada en SQLite, he estado navegando y no encuentro nada que yo entienda

```
public List<string> DimeColumnas()
    {
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        SQLiteCommand cmd = this.conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = string.Format("pragma table_info({0})", this.tabla);
        SQLiteDataReader lector  = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Console.WriteLine(conn.FileName);
        Console.WriteLine();
        int i = 0;
        while (lector.Read())
        {
            lst.Add(lector.GetName(i)); 
            i++; 
        }
        return lst;
    }
```

En teoría me debería devolver una lista con los nombres de las columnas de dicha tabla y lo que me devuelve no es lo esperado (cid,name,type) es loque me devuelve.

gracias de antemano

Comment: en donde tienes tu query? por que lo que consultas es table_info deberías tener tu select buscando los nombres.

Answer (score 0):

os dejo una posible solución, por lo menos me da el resultado esperado.
lo que si quisiera es si alguien lo resuelve de forma distinta lo publicara o si aun dándome el resultado esperado no es lo correcto, me gustaría que lo publicara ya que soy muy nuevo en programación y autodidacta, muchas gracias por su atención

```
public List<object> Dime_Columnas(string tabla)
    {
        commando = this.con.CreateCommand();
        commando.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM "+tabla;
        lector = commando.ExecuteReader();
        for (int i = 0; i < lector.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            lst.Add(lector.GetName(i).ToString());
        }
        return lst;
    }
```